# Why Redux use the term "Selector"?

Tags: reactjs, redux, naming, reselect

The term "Selector" sounds quite confusing to me.

In official doc [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html#). It makes sense to name the mapping procedure "select" cuz you are indeed filtering something. kinda "select a different piece of the redux store".

But theoretically, you can do any kinda computation within the `MapThingsToProps` functions, like transforming a flatten data structure to a nested one that your UI component need, or compute some temp data.

Are names such as "Adaptor", "Data Transformer", or even "Mapper" are better than "Selector"?

Or if I misunderstand the meaning of "select" or the "selecting process"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The term "selector" appears to have first been used in [redux#47](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/47#issuecomment-114261927), and the idea was inspired by the "getter" concept from the NuclearJS library..  I don't see a specific mention of *why* that term was used.  However, the first couple iterations of `connect()` used the name `select` for the data retrieval function instead of `mapStateToProps`, so I'm guessing it came from that.

Overall, I think you're overthinking the terminology a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it must be something similar to the SQL SELECT. There is normalized data stored in a RDB or Redux store and you can select a projection of this data with some denormalization or convolution, or even select anything you want such as a constant or current date.

Comment: If your question is not about the name but is rather about the internals of a selector, then you just need selectors because of memoization process that is applied to every selector and increase overall performance dramatically.